# DDD - Aggregate - Should getters be really avoided?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, aggregate, getter, ddd-repositories

Good morning,

I've read many time that both setters and getters should be avoided in AR. While I can understand the reason for the setters, I disagree a bit regarding the getters when those are clearly part of the business.

Let's imagine the following **User** AR:

```php
namespace vendor\Domain\Model;

class User
{
    private $userId;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $email;

    static public register(...): User { ... } // Ubiquitous Language
    public function unregister(...) { ... } // Ubiquitous Language
    public function changePassword(...) { ... } // Ubiquitous Language
    public function changeEmail(...) { ... } // Ubiquitous Language
    public function getAggregateId(): UserId { ... } // A getter
    public function getUsername(): UserName { ... } // A getter
    public function getEmail(): UserEmail { ... } // A getter
    ...
}
```

Now let's imagine the following **UserRepository** interface:

```php
namespace vendor\Domain;

interface UserRepository
{
    public function userOfId(UserId $userId):? User;
    public function userOfname(UserName $userName):? User;
    public function userOfEmail(UserEmail $userEmail):? User;
    ...
}
```

Basically here, I've some finders which make it possible to retrieve a **User** by its ID, its username, or its email address.

Now, let's imagine the following **in-memory** implementation of that **UserRepository**:

```php
namespace vendor\Infrastructure\Persistence;

use vendor\Domain\UserRepository;

class InMemoryUserRepository implements UserRepository
{
    /** User[] */
    private $users;

    public function userOfId(UserId $userId):? User
    {
        if(!isset($this->users[$userId->tostring()]) {
            return null;
        }

        $this->users[$userId->tostring()];
    }

    public function userOfEmail(UserEmail $userEmail):? User
    {
        foreach($users as $user) {
            if($user->getEmail()->sameValueAs($userEmail) {
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, in that **in-memory** implementation, I need filter users by email, accessing their email property. This necessarily means that the **User** AR needs to provide the **getEmail()** getter. It is really bad? It is allowed to have getters for properties which must be accessed? Should I simply considere that the **getEmail()** getter has a business meaning, in which case, it is perfectly valid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Getter are fine. The case of "don't write getters" is to avoid exposing internal state outside the aggregate: when your services take the aggregate, fetch its state, and make some decision based on that. That's what you want to avoid.

You could follow the guideline of the Law of Demeter, and aim for that. Don't strictly avoid getter, but be mindful about them.

Having a `getId` or `getUsername` is perfectly fine.
Having a `getCollection`-kind of method that returns a mutable collection is not. The aggregate lose control on what it's an internal details, an implementation details. When you expose something like `getFriends()`, your services could call it, add or delete things outside the aggregate, and you basically lose the ability  refactor the aggregate without breaking everything. an `addFriend()` and `deleteFriend()` in that case would solve it. And if `getFriends()` returns an *immutable* collection, it's fine as well.

*Don't write getters* is not an hard rule, try not to expose too much state outside the aggregate, but don't unnecessarily complicate your life by not have *any* getters at all. Use them if it make sense.

Comment: Exactly my through. I wanted just to be sure. Thank you for your contribution. That's much appreciated.

Comment: @Federkun, so when I have an invoice aggregate, that has a LineItemsCollection and I have an InvoiceCalculator service, how would I implement this? The Calculator needs to read from the collections items to be able to calculate nett, gross and VAT and maybe other taxes as well. Also how would you update the price on the invoice? I thought about doing Invoice::calculate(Calculator $calculator) and having the calculators calculate method take an instance of the invoice to read from it. Sounds good?

Comment: But what about if I have application service that interacts with a repository to save the aggregate details, then I need getters from the aggregate to send them to the repository to be written to the db, right?
@floriank

Comment: @tareksalem if you save the aggregate you either use reflection, or a toArray() method or events (event sourcing) that are then stored in an event store and then a subscriber picks these events up and stores the actual changes to a DB (read model). I've explored both ways and they just work fine for me. I actually use a toArray() and jsonSerialize() to store snapshots of the aggregate and reflection to extract the events from it. My aggregate is a clean POPO without external dependencies. The write repository gets the event & snapshot store injected and saves actually all my aggregates.